# Как на php разобрать массив ld+json?

Tags: php, json

На странице сайта есть разметка schema.org, она заключена в теги:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>...</script>
```

Я извлек все что внутри этих тегов.

По началу я подумал что это получиться обычный json массив, и после

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

все будет как нужно. Но это оказалось не так...

Каким образом привести это к json массиву или как получить с него нужные мне данные по ключам(как это делается в обычном json). ?

Comment: Хорошо бы пример данных

Comment: Приведите пример данных в вопрос.